# Python Finding lines between two quotation marks precedeed by a specific word

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like that :

```
This is a text file 
game: 
"
a
b
"
symbol : "o"
```

I want to take lines that is next to "game:" and that are between the quotation marks. 
I tried to use re such as :

```
contents = file.read()
re.findall((?<=game)"([^"]*)",contents)
```

But this doesn't work... 
Can someone help me please? 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You need to account for the newlines and whitespace among and after `game: "`:

```
re.findall(r"game: \n\"\n([^\"]*)",contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern. Let me know if you need any adjustments `(?<=game: \n").*?(?=")`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AtjNlA/1)

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose your regex in single quotes since your pattern looks for double quotes:

```
import re
s = '''This is a text file
game: 
"
a
b
"
symbol : "o"'''
print(re.findall(r'game:\s*\n"\n([^"]*)"', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['a\nb\n']
```